# Importing /scraping page content form other sites?

Tags: php, parsing, web-scraping

i've been playing with php and also http://www.alchemyapi.com/, and embed.ly
but i was wondering if there other options out there to import and parse a webpage, any page, either is a news site or a blog...

thanks

Comment: Tell us what exactly are you looking for when you say "other options", as otherwise this is a very open ended question.

Answer (score 2):

To fetch the data: [`curl`](http://php.net/curl), [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/file_get_contents) (may be others those are the two common)

To parse the data: [`PHP: DOM`](http://php.net/dom), [`SimpleXML`](http://php.net/simplexml) [`preg_match`](http://php.net/preg_match)**

Since it was tagged with PHP, I only gave working information for PHP. There are tons of ways to do this, if you can narrow your question down to what you are trying to do it would help. The better ways to parse any site, is through their RSS feed if they have one, or through their API, speculating that they offer up the content you want via RSS/API.

---

** `preg_match` is not a great alternative it does "work" but better to use the DOM / Simple XML functions if possible.

Comment: i'm just trying to save post or news for personal use from external websites, so they maynot have an api, or their RSS is not complete

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a crawler at work using `cURL` and `preg_match`

Before I chose to do it that way, I had looked at DOM Parsers http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php